# Webpack plugin: Find file that belongs to CallExpression

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to write a webpack plugin and I'm tapping into `CallExpressions` on the `parser`.

How can I find out **which file** the current `CallExpression` belongs to?

```js
compiler.hooks.normalModuleFactory.tap("MyWebpackPlugin", (factory) => {
  factory.hooks.parser
    .for("javascript/auto")
    .tap("MyWebpackPlugin", (parser, options) => {
      parser.hooks.evaluate
        .for("CallExpression")
        .tap("MyWebpackPlugin", (callExpression) => {
          //
          // How can I find the file where this CallExpression occurred?
          //
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I've solved it with the following code:

```
compiler.hooks.normalModuleFactory.tap("MyPlugin", (factory) => {
  factory.hooks.createModule.tap("MyPlugin", (module) => {
    if (!module.parser.hooks) {
      return;
    }

    module.parser.hooks.evaluate
      .for("CallExpression")
      .tap("MyPlugin", (callExpression) => {
        console.log(">>> CallExpression");
        console.log(module.request);
      });
  });
});
```